# Executing containers on multiple architectures

Tags: docker, containers, mips, powerpc, lxd

I am trying to get some services up and running on various CPU architectures like ppc, mips and x86_64 using docker containers.

From what I could read so far, docker engine is supported for a few platforms and unless I use qemu(like in https://resin.io/blog/building-arm-containers-on-any-x86-machine-even-dockerhub/) or cross docker (https://github.com/justincormack/cross-docker), I can't run my "other" arch binaries on a docker-engine. I had tried a bit of the qemu attempts, but it stopped with the binfmt_misc modifications that seems to be central to getting these to run.